# How to record video when using face detection api

Tags: android-camera, video-capture, face-detection

I'm using the android FaceDetector to detect faces. I base on code 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker

I want to save the video preview. I have not found a solution , are looking forward to get the best guidance , or a link. Thank all

Comment: did you find anything

Comment: can you please paste a example code here?